# Complex Ebean Query

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

i am trying to make ebean query for this case: i want to filter users based on their last_update_time and update_frequency(in days) the query should get the users when `last_update_time.plusDays(update_frequency)<now().`

my query now looks like this:

```
List<User> users = Ebean.find(User.class).where().lt("last_update_time",DateTime.now()).findList();
```

i need to add update_frequency to the last_update_time.
any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `last_update_time.plusDays(update_frequency)<now()` ... is valid SQL (for your DB) then you can just pass that in via the "raw" expression. query.where().raw(...) like:

```
  List<User> users =
  Ebean.find(User.class)
    .where()
      .lt("last_update_time",DateTime.now())
      .raw("last_update_time.plusDays(update_frequency)<now()")
      .findList()
```